# css - table in div going over it

Tags: html, css

Can you tell me why the table cell with text is going out of the `div`?

My code:
http://nocleg-i.pl/1969/wyszukane/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a long text link is the culprit here. In cases such as these, you can simply use CSS to force word-wrapping. Just apply the following to your stylesheet and voila!

```
div.text_exposed {
 word-wrap: break-word;
 width: 500px;
}
```

(Please note that it is required to set a width for the word-wrap rule to apply)

Comment: @user1515076 Try my edited answer, let me know if it works :]

Answer (score 0):

As @Vinny Burgh said, the long link is the problem. However, Don't leave the anchor tags blank. Add some words to it so the url doesn't show up and the content doesn't break.

```
<a href="the_actual_extra_long_link">Missing text-Input text here</a>
```

Basically, you have to put some text where I imply above.

Or, it could be a html bug, maybe some unclosed anchor like this:

```
<a href="the_actual_extra_long_link double quotes to close the href and a &gt; symbol may be missing </a>
```

Comment: Ok, im not the owner or creator of this site, i just have to do something with it to prevent situation like this.
So i need some solution to wrap or shorten these links.

Comment: It is simply an html bug, just check the link and make sure it is closed like `<a></a>`

Comment: tags are ok, and your missing text is the same as link, so all i need is wrap or do something with this...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="id_4f4e2a34992008a12697010" class="text_exposed_root text_exposed">
```

It's working good when I translated to English, browser does not support your language.
I think the problem is in your class. Remove the `div` class and and retry.